# Mapping an API response to a class when the JSON returned doesn't exactly match the class in an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am making a call to a public API that returns the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "xyz": "abc123"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "event_id": "ggldfgsdl343409534095kgdflkgdslk",
            "event_name": "Event 1",
        },
        {
            "event_id": "214732hdfghdfghj43348fgdfgkjfdkf",
            "event_name": "Event 2",
        },
        {
            "event_id": "35345dsfgdgkjdfgdkjg49343djfgdfk",
            "event_name": "Event 3",
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a class called Event:

```
export class Event {
    eventId: String;
    eventName: String;
}
```

Here is the call to the API in my EventService:

```
  getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventApiUrl, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

I am aware of a few things:

1. The property names of my class do not match the property names in the JSON response.
2. The only way this would work as it appears above is if the
   property names matched the property names in the JSON and the API
   returned an array of objects directly
3. I think I need to use pipe(map()) but can't get it working

I would like to know how I can drill down one level into the "events" array and return the list of objects in it as Event[] while accounting for the property name mismatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
  return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventApiUrl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return res.events.map(e => {
        return { eventId: e.event_id, eventName: e.event_name };
      })
    });
  );
}
```

You indeed need a `map`. Loop through `events` prop inside your response object and build a new object from each.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly my problem. So first we set the response to type any because it can be anything. Then we run map on the events array which allows us to set the property names. Now if the property names weren't different we wouldn't need to do the second map right?

Comment: If they weren't differen't so yes, wouldn't need a second `map`. Type `any` you could replace with your `interface`, which would be a Js object with a shape of a JSON object you posted. But thats not necessary in this case as you do not have control of the incoming values, so yes, it basically would be any

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'pluck' and then 'map' to first extract the 'events' from the response and then map them.

```
this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventApiUrl, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        pluck('events'),
        map((events: any[]) => events.map((event: any) => 
            ({eventId: event.event_id, eventName: event.event_name})))
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have never used pluck before. This is pretty cool! If I adjust my class so the property names match and didn't need to map the property names I could simply call pluck('events') right?

Comment: Slight change here:  ({eventId: event.event_id, eventName: event.event_name})))

Comment: Noticing I might need to specify what events is. Getting an error property map does not exist on type 'unknown'

Comment: I think this does the trick: (events: any) => events.map(). It appears to be working, update your answer if you agree.

Comment: That's a fair point, perhaps (events: any[]) or (events: {event_id: string, event_name: string}[])  would be better since it would make the code more self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
 getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventApiUrl, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(ary => ary.map(x => ({
        eventId: x.event_id,
        eventName: x.event_name
      })
    )
  }
```

What you're likely missing, and what bit me, is that what goes into the .map() is your array that comes back from the get(), not each individual object, so you then need to map over that array as well.